# How to remove a chracter in a list of strings -Python

Tags: python, string, list, hyperlink, python-3.7

I got a list of links that I'll need to use for another program, but the problem is that they have a number and a paranthese at the beginning like:

1. https://instagram.com/p/link1
2. https://instagram.com/p/link2
   ..

First I converted them to a list with the following code:

```
links = []
n = int(input("How many links u got:"))
for j in range(1, n+1):
    v = str(input())
    links.append(v)
```

and output is:
['1) https://instagram.com/p/link1','2) https://instagram.com/p/link2']

Now I need to remove the number and the parenthese.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x, link in enumerate(links):
    links[x] = link.split(") ")[1]
```

This will remove the starting `"1) "` and `"2) "` from the items.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern in the elements of the list. If I understood correctly, you need to have only the part after the white space in your strings. You can change your last line to:

```
links.append(v.split(' ')[1])
```

In this line, you are going to split the line using white space, and use the second part of the string. For further information [look here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Uzun Emre.. Thank you <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't add in `"1) "`, so I am presuming that it's part of the user input that isn't going to change?

If it's user generated content, you might want to consider checking for the presence of the `)` before trying to remove it.

I minimally modified your code so that it splits on the `)` if it is present in the user input, and I added in the removal of leading spaces to account for the `"1)http://..."` case.

Without knowing more about the problem it's difficult to guide you more, but I am making the assumption that the `)` won't appear in the link itself as well.

```
links = []
n = int(input("How many links u got:"))
for j in range(1, n+1):
    v = str(input())
    v = v.rsplit(')')[1] if ')' in v else v
    links.append(v.lstrip(' '))
```